# Trouble linking with glfw

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, undefined-reference, glad

I'm using codeblocks and MinGW and windows 10.

I put the directory for the include folder for glad and GLFW under compiler under search directories. I put the directory for the lib folder for GLFW under compiler under search directories. I also put libopengl32.a, libglfw3.a and libglfw3dll.a under Linker settings.

Errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'|
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c|| undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 31 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback( GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height );
void processInput( GLFWwindow* window );

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                 "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                 "void main()\n"
                                 "{\n"
                                 " gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
                                 "}\0";
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                   "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                   "void main()\n"
                                   "{\n"
                                   " FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                   "}\n\0";

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback( window, framebuffer_size_callback );

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if( !gladLoadGLLoader( (GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // build and compile our shader program
    // ------------------------------------
    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vertexShader );

    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[ 512 ];
    glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    if( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv( fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
    if( !success )
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog( fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // link shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
    glLinkProgram( shaderProgram );

    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv( shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success );
    if( !success )
    {
        glGetProgramInfoLog( shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog );
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader( vertexShader );
    glDeleteShader( fragmentShader );

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left
        0.5f,  -0.5f, 0.0f, // right
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f  // top
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );

    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray( VAO );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof( float ), (void*)0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

    // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
    // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
    glBindVertexArray( 0 );

    // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    // render loop
    // -----------
    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput( window );

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor( 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // draw our first triangle
        glUseProgram( shaderProgram );
        // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
        glBindVertexArray( VAO );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
        // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );
    glDeleteProgram( shaderProgram );

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput( GLFWwindow* window )
{
    if( glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) == GLFW_PRESS )
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose( window, true );
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback( GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height )
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
}
```

Comment: What is printed in the "build log" tab?

Comment: -------------- Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -LC:\GL\glfw\lib -o bin\Debug\test.exe obj\Debug\glad.o obj\Debug\main.o   "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libopengl32.a" C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3dll.a
C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
31 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: That's only part of it as the full build log was too long

Comment: `C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3.a C:\GL\glfw\lib\libglfw3dll.a`  You don't need both. The first one is used if you want to link GLFW statically, and the second one is for dynamic linking. Removing the first one might fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by linking my project to `libgdi32.a`, which should be located in the `lib` folder in your MinGW install folder.

I'm not sure how it works on Code::Blocks, but on the command line with g++ you just add `-lgdi32` to your command line options.